# Calculate maximum value of a time based running total measure and filtering time table based on another table

Tags: date, filter, powerbi, max, cumulative-sum

**Here is the situation (POWERBI):**

- I have 2 tables: one calendar table named *"CALENDAR"* and one fact table called *"DELIBERE"*
- I have a time based running total measure called "DELIBERE PIANIFICATE RT" that calculates the RT value counting the "PROVA" column of the *"DELIBERE"* table based on the "Date" column of the *"CALENDAR"* table
- I need to calculate the max value of the "DELIBERE PIANIFICATE RT" and have it constant for all dates.

**Here is the problem:**

- The "DELIBERE PIANIFICATE RT" measures is calculated as below:

```
DELIBERE PIANIFICATE RT = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(DELIBERE[PROVA]),  FILTER( ALLSELECTED('CALENDAR'[Date]), 'CALENDAR'[Date]<= MAX(DELIBERE[DATA])), DELIBERE[PIANO]="PIANIFICATA")
```

- The max RT values is calculated as below:

```
DELIBERE PIANIFICATE TOT = MAXX(ALL('CALENDAR'[Date]), [DELIBERE PIANIFICATE RT])
```

- It works but it ends up calculating the Max RT values for all dates within the calendar table, which makes it really slow.
- I'd like to have it calculated only for the rows in which the CALENDARE table has a "Date" finding a match within the "DATA" column of the "DELIBERE" Table.

[image: database query result]

I tried with `LOOKUPVALUE`, `RELATED`, `CONTAINS`, `IN VALUES`,... with no success.

Can someone give me a trick?